# Navbar gets properties of background image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a navbar over an tranparent background but when I create navbar it also gets the properties of background image. Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

[image]

This is the HTML for the Menu:

```
<section>  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <img src="logo.png" style="padding-left: 50px; margin-top: 5%">
      </div>  

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" style="color: white"> HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: white"> SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: white"> ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: white"> TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: white"> CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.navbar {
  background:transparent;
  background-image:none;
  border-color:transparent;
  box-shadow:none;        
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
}
{
  box-sizing: border-box;        
}

body {         
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}       

.container-fluid {
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 0px;   
}      

.container-fluid img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.container-fluid .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,178,170,0.5); /* Black background with transparency */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the code of your current attempt?

Comment: Give background color to your navbar

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Luca I dont know how to post code, can u plz guide

Comment: @iqrashaheen I have edited the code into the question, if you accept it, the code will be there. I had to add some extra text for my edit to be accepted, but did not change to much (hopefully)

Comment: @Luca ok thanku so much

Comment: @iqrashaheen your welcome

Comment: can anyone please correct my code according to my problem

Comment: @iqrashaheen yeah that might still be a good idea. I tried to edit out as much code as possible, but still did is kinda quick, so I might still have code there that is not needed

Comment: @Luca ask your friends to solve my issue if you can.

Comment: @iqrashaheen I know shahid just updated his answer, might be useful to take a look at that

Comment: @Luca where he updated?

Comment: @iqrashaheen his answer was updated 7 minutes ago. It is one of the 2 answers on this question

Answer (score 0):

Please use `navbar-light` or `navbar-dark` so the link colors work against the contrast of the background image or color
somewhat like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light transparent">
```

*or*

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark transparent">
```

Comment: its not working, i want transparent background and navbar over that background, but when i make navbar ,navbar also gets colours of background

Comment: ok, you share your code please, that will be helpful for users to solve the issue you are facing

Comment: how to share the whole code here?
should I  post as comment?

Comment: edit your question, paste html,css and script, and you'll get tips how to highlight code: Select your code and then use the {} button above the editor

Comment: no dont post it as comment, edit it in your question that will be helpful for rest of the users also

Comment: @iqrashaheen thats what the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) page is for :) And make sure to reduce your code to the [minimum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you need to reproduce the issue.

Comment: yup go thru the tour page as suggested by @MatthiasSeifert or else go to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) paste your code there, give it a title and FORK it and then share the link here

Comment: @MohdTabishBaig now please solve my issue, I dont want to make navbar get the properties of image.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use background-image with background overlay.

```css
.image {
  background-color: #490d40;
  background: url(https://sonorangirl.github.io/Earth-Quotes/img/google-earth-view-South-Iceland3.jpg)
    no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.image:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(51, 23, 14, 0.6);
}
.navbar {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="image"></div>
</body>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/shahidali/pen/JZKrON)

Comment: Why would anyone ever need a `z-index` of `999`?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a class `header` to the `section` element which contains the nav-bar and added this style:

```
.header { position: relative; z-index: 2; }
```

The header will position itself on top of the background.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/y817zo62/